# Listbox customization - add category titles for specific items

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, controls

Which is the best way to perform the following:

Lets say i have a listbox with dynamic data binding.
The items inside are sorted based on the item category.

Now i would like to partition lets say the items and put a title above each category (only once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [LongListSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api). It is a free control that is a part of the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). A lot of stock applications are using this categorization method and it makes your application be a bit more consistent with the platform.

Comment: It looks perfect.. could it work to group items by date as well? (items for today / tomorrow / other)

Comment: Sure, the grouping criteria is determined by the developer.

Comment: i ve notived - i can actually do anything i want!! Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [LongListSelector control.](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)

Download from [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)